# How to pass parameters to a javascript function from the element that calls the function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of `<li>` items, which call the same `onmouseover` javascript function. 
The function needs to extract some data from the element that calls it, to fill some `name` and `tel` variables. This data is typed in capitals in the html code below.
Any idea on how to do this is really appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<li id="item1" onmouseover= "onmouseoveragent(this)" >
<a href="some link">
    <span class="hideme">name</span>
</a>
    <p class="hideme"> NAME TO BE PASSED TO JS
    <strong class="tel">NUMBER TO BE PASSED TO JS</strong>
</p>
</li>
```

MY javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function onmouseoveragent(e) {
        var name = e.?????;
    var tel = e.?????;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is an easier way to do it, just traverse the childNodes of your current hovered element and parse the results. Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Udm/) of the snippet below(yes, it works with all the LIs matching that structure):

```
function onmouseoveragent(e) {
    var children = this.childNodes,
        name = null,
        tel = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        if (child.tagName === 'P') {
            name = child.firstChild.nodeValue; // the first node is the text node
            tel = child.childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue; // the strong's text node
            break; // let's stop the iteration, we've got what we needed and the loop has no reason to go on
        }
    }
    console.log(name, tel); // "NAME TO BE PASSED TO JS " "NUMBER TO BE PASSED TO JS"
}
```

The only difference in HTML is that you need to pass your handler this way:

```
<li id="item1" onmouseover="onmouseoveragent.call(this, event)">
```

So `this` inside the handler will refer to the element and not to the global object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great, only I need `e.offsetTop` and `e.offsetLeft` in my javascript function, but they seem to be 0 (or not have any value at all). Don't know why..

Comment: @Yalda use `this`(which refers to the element), since `e` is the `event` object

Answer (score 3):

yes you do something like this

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('data-item');

var mouseoverHandler = function() {
   var name = this.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].textContent,
       tel = this.getElementsByClassName('tel')[0].textContent;
    alert('Name - ' + name + "\nTel - " + tel);
}

for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
     var current = elements[i];
     current.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverHandler);
}
```

**HTML MARKUP**:

```
<li id="item1" class="data-item"> 
    <a href="some link">
        <span class="hideme">name</span>
    </a>

    <p class="hideme">
        <span class="name">John Smith</span>
        <strong class="tel">555-666-777</strong>
    </p>
</li>

<li id="item1" class="data-item"> 
    <a href="some link">
        <span class="hideme">name</span>
    </a>

    <p class="hideme">
        <span class="name">Caprica Smith</span>
        <strong class="tel">545-334-641</strong>
    </p>
</li>
```

[**MDN** - *document.getElementsByClassName();*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

[**MDN** - *element.textContent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.textContent)

> It won't be `e.something` because `e` is referring to the `event` that just happened, that has nothing to do the other `elements` in the `DOM`
>
> ## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZEWv/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have several of such `<li>`s and all of them have tags with class name `hideme` and `tel`, with a different text. Using this approach, the variables are filled with contents of the first `<li>` no matter for which `onmouseover` has happened

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in all browsers(for instance, not in IE < 9)

Comment: Neither is `addEventListener` or `textContent`

Comment: Yes, but they are easy to fix since there are already `innerText` and `attachEvent` for IE support

Comment: so is `getElementsByClassName` loop through the elements children and check and push `indexOf(className)` return it

Comment: It's not built-in method, you should create it yourself, which is not the same thing ;)

Comment: But. you get the same result. so it is the same thing?

Comment: Well, it's quite similar, but not the exact same thing I guess

Comment: It's always better when `getElementsByClassName` is factory sealed isn't it :)

Comment: Yes it is lol, infact the best thing is... SHAME ON YOU, IE! :P

Comment: Thanks a lot smart javascript guys! Trying to study @Connor 's answer and the comments :)

Comment: That's not smart. in a few months time when you have mastered the basics, you will be saying that all over again

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you two thing one change the structure of you li tag i.e; make the tag as shown

```
<li id="item1" class="someClass" >
<a href="some link">
<span class="hideme">name</span>
</a>
<p class="hideme">NAME TO BE PASSED TO JS </p>
<strong class="tel">NUMBER TO BE PASSED TO JS</strong>
</li>
```

remove strong from p because when you try to fetch p(data to be passed the strong tag will come along with it so better change it)

and also try jquery it will give you more flexibility and ease of use(what i feel)

```
$(".someClass").mouseover(function(e){
    var name = $(e.target).find("p:first").html()
    var tel = $(e.target).find("strong:first").html()
```

})

Answer (score 0):

try this

> function onmouseoveragent(e) {
>
> ```
>     var text = e.getElementsByClassName('hideme')[1].textContent;
>       var name = text.split("\n")[0];     var num = text.split("\n")[1];  alert(name);    alert(num); }
> ```